# Eliminar mismo elemento en 2 arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente consulta.

He intentado eliminar el mismo valor en 2 arrays diferentes de la siguiente manera:

```
const arr1 = [2,3,6,8,7];
const arr2 = [5,2,4,9,1];

arr1.forEach((num1, i1) => {
 arr2.forEach((num2, i2) => {
  if(num1 === num2){
   arr1.splice(i1, 1)
   arr2.splice(i2, 1)
  }
 })
})
```

Resultado: En este caso elimina el 2.

```
const arr1 = [3, 6, 8, 7]
const arr2 = [5, 4, 9, 1]
```

El problema que tengo y que no funciona es que si el numero que subsigiente al ya eliminado tambien esta repetido, no funciona por que entiendo que pasa a ocupar el index del valor eliminado y por lo tanto el forEach no lo va a recorrer por que ya lo recorrio.

Ejemplo:

```
const arr1 = [2,3,6,8,7];
const arr2 = [5,2,3,9,1];
```

Resultado:

```
const arr1 = [3, 6, 8, 7];
const arr2 = [5, 3, 9, 1];
```

En este caso me elimina el 2 pero no el 3.

Alguna solución al código que realicé?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podes implementar una funcion con el metodo de arrays `filter()` que devuelve un array con los elementos del array objetivo que cumplan la condicion:

```js
let arr1 = [2,3,6,8,7,3,3];
let arr2 = [5,2,4,9,1,5,5];

// la funcion devuelve un array con todos los elementos que cumplen la condicion
const deleteNum = (number,arr) => arr.filter(elem => elem !== number); 

arr1 = deleteNum(3,arr1); // pasas el array objetivo y el numero a eliminar, ahora arr1 tiene los elementos eliminados
arr2 = deleteNum(9,arr2);

arr1 = deleteNum(2,arr1);
arr2 = deleteNum(5,arr2);

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Cualquier cosa pregunta.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de ponerlo en un snippet para que pueda ejecutarlo y comprobar su funcionamiento,

Comment: gracias @masterguru

Comment: Me parece que esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta del OP, ya que requiere de antemano que se conozcan los elementos repetidos. Él no quiere eliminar un número en particular, quiere eliminar todos los número que estén en ambos array

Answer (score 0):

No es muy buena idea recorrer un array y modificarlo en cada iteración. Tampoco es necesario hacer 2 for, puedes consultar si un item del primer array está en el segundo usando indexOf

Además existe un tema de mutabilidad en los array, en mi opinión una buena función no debe modificar un array, sino que debe devolver uno nuevo (obviamente puede haber excepciones). Luego uno siempre puede sobreescribir el original. Algo como esto:

```
let array=[//elementos];
array = array.function();
```

Te dejo una solución que usa "reduce" para crear un nuevo array que no contiene los elementos del array2. Además tiene un argumento opcional, para sobrescribir o no el argumento de entrada.

```js
let arr1 = [2,3,6,8,7];
let arr2 = [5,2,3,9,1];

Array.prototype.EliminarCoincidentes = function(arr,sobreescribir){
   return this.reduce((a,e) => {
    let i = arr.indexOf(e);
    if(i>=0){
      if(sobreescribir==null || sobreescribir){
        arr.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    else{
      a.push(e);
    }
    return a;
  } ,[]);
};

arr1 = arr1.EliminarCoincidentes(arr2);

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```